# missing java.lang and other basic libraries in my IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Cannot resolve method on getString.

I'm fairly sure my path is just screwed up or something, this is a fresh jdk 1.8 install I did yesterday and reinstalled tonight, using intelliJ and Eclipse I don't have access to basic methods like getString and length, and if I manually add the libraries to my java file, they aren't found.

SOME libs are still available and can be found (though I had to point them out to my IDE to fix them automatically), like

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

I would just install missing libraries manually but things as basic as java.lang I can't find downloads for.  What is wrong with my Java installation?  I just installed from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Can I check my folder for missing things?

I've set the following environment variables:

```
CLASSPATH C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin;.

PATH C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Python\Python35\Scripts;C:\Program Files\nodejs\

JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
```

Comment: You have not included JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101 in the path variable. why? ClassPath specifies where .class files are located.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a solution for your issue. But I could find these flaws in you SO question. You have not included `JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101` in the path variable. Class Path specifies the location for JVM to find the .class files that get generated by your program. you can include as many path just by specifying `;`

Answer (score 0):

I would start with Intellij settings, cause it looks like bad project configuration.
`shift+ctrl+alt+s` or `File > Project Structure` 
from there `Project Settings > Project > Project SDK` set correct JDK